# Как правильно выровнять последний flex элемент?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

Внутри flex блока есть элементы с фиксированной шириной. Их может быть любое количество. Нужно чтобы в ряд помещалось столько элементов сколько влезет, и это собственно должно всё центрироваться на странице.  Если делать `justify-content: center`  Это последние элементы будут в центре если их будем мало.

[image http://goo.gl/Poj761](http://goo.gl/Poj761)

Хотелось бы выровнять по левому краю. Если делать after элемент последний на всю ширину, то ломаются отступы

[image http://goo.gl/xNjtQi](http://goo.gl/xNjtQi)

Можно ли как-то решить это с помощью flex? Если нет, то какие есть варианты решения?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/egorava/pen/QEdBaJ)

Comment: Вот [решение](http://codepen.io/AndyMaleh/pen/xGNPrX/), но оно использует фильтр и не работает на iPad. Вся [дискуссия](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) аналогичного вопроса (на англ.)

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что вы решили проблему? На Codepen, кажется, рабочий вариант?